# How to parse an ISO8601 date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date, iso8601

I got string of date regarding this format:

```
2011-12-29T09:09:06-0500
```

How can I convert this into a date object?

Comment: did you search on SO or google?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194998/whats-the-right-way-to-parse-an-iso8601-date-in-cocoa , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925038/why-nsdateformatter-can-not-parse-date-from-iso-8601-format , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559912/date-time-parsing-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-12-29T09:09:06-0500";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];    
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@" dateFromString %@",dateFromString);
```

Comment: Does this pick up the TZ or whack it off at Zulu or...? (I don't using anything iX.)

Comment: This fails on lots of ISO8601 date strings, e.g. "2013-11-27T11:28:10.201-08:00". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Is there anything more comprehensive?

Comment: swift version:

` let date = "2008-12-29T00:27:42-0800"
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ")
            let final = formatter.dateFromString(date) `

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *date = [[NSDate date] description];

[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:<NSString containing date>];
```