# How to parse date string with this format (Ex: 2012-04-12T14:23:23)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to parse date string with this format (Ex: 2012-04-12T14:23:23).
I try with this format string but It's wrong: yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2008-12-3T22:11:30"];
```

Answer (score 7):

You should escape the letter `T`:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
```

Answer (score 1):

That's ISO 8601 date format. So, the best way to do this is with a specific date parser that will make life easy for you.

That can be found here http://boredzo.org/iso8601parser/.

Also, have a search on "ISO 8601". You'll find plenty of resources and example, e.g.

[What's the right way to parse an ISO8601 date in cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194998/whats-the-right-way-to-parse-an-iso8601-date-in-cocoa)

[Is there a simple way of converting an ISO8601 timestamp to a formatted NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201216/is-there-a-simple-way-of-converting-an-iso8601-timestamp-to-a-formatted-nsdate)